# Does the MPP Player framework support RTSP?

Tags: windows-phone-8, rtsp, live-streaming

Does the [MPP Player framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/) support playing files over the real time streaming protocol on WP8?

I've tried the following:

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Source="rtsp://78.129.192.5:1935/akdrd/dunyalive.mp4"
                   Margin="0,11,0,214"
                   Grid.Row="1">
    <mmppf:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
        <adaptive:AdaptivePlugin />
    </mmppf:MediaPlayer.Plugins> 
</mmppf:MediaPlayer>
```

Comment: I have tried this as <mmppf:MediaPlayer Source = "rtsp://78.129.192.5:1935/akdrd/dunyalive.mp4" Margin="0,11,0,214" Grid.Row="1">
     <mmppf:MediaPlayer.Plugins> 
     <adaptive:AdaptivePlugin /> 
     </mmppf:MediaPlayer.Plugins> 
</mmppf:MediaPlayer>

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes, This video failed to play, here is the screencast.http://screencast.com/t/PbntvbdgPNO

Comment: any 1 here to help me????